# jQuery Progress Bar Loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, progress-bar

I am experiencing difficulty figuring out how to break out of this progress bar after the final download completes. I have tried break and return false and neither seems to work. The page is supposed to load and then the progress bar begins the first download then goes through the second and third downloads and should stop after the 3rd download and present an alert or dialog box stating "Complete" - with a button that redirects the user to another URL when clicked. I know it is something simple that I am missing but can't figure out how to accomplish this. If any guru's out there can lend a hand I would appreciate it.

```
    <head>
  <title>Download Page</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


  <script>
    var i=0;
    var u=0;

function fnc(){
    setInterval(function(){
    document.getElementById("bar").style.width=i+"%";
    document.getElementById("bar").innerHTML=i+"%";
    document.getElementById("u1").innerHTML=i+"%";

    i++;
    if(u===0){document.getElementById("u1").innerHTML="Download 1";}
    if(u===1){document.getElementById("u1").innerHTML="Download 2";}
    if(u===2){document.getElementById("u1").innerHTML="Download 3";}


    if(i===100){

        u++; 
        i=0;}
    }, 150);
}

</script>

</head>
<body onload="fnc()">

<div class="container">
  <h3 id="u1">Starting downloads</h3>
    <div class="progress">
    <div id="bar" class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've used `setInterval` which means "keep doing this".

You could use `setTimeout` and keep adding a new timeout or you could store the result of `setInterval` and then use `clearInterval` when finished:

```
// create update as a separate function instead of inline
function update() {
    ...
    // update finished, just return
    if (u===4) return;
    // not finished, start again
    setTimeout(update, 150);
}
// start update checks
setInterval(update, 150);
```

or

```
var timer = null;
timer = setInterval(function() {
    // update finished, cancel timeout
    if (u===4) { clearInterval(timer); }
}, 150);
```

Personal preference is the first one as you have more control over restarting the loop and don't run the risk of starting a second loop before the first has finished.